# Set Style for Content Editor Web Part in Sharepoint Designer 2010

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, content-editor-web-part, web-part-zone, cewp

I have created a new page layout and added a web part zone. In this web part zone I have also added a content editor web part. When users go into edit mode on the page and add content to the CEWP, i want the text to be formatted uniformly - meaning i want to set the style for the CEWP. An example would be font size should be 12px and font-family should be arial.

How would i force this to happen?

Also - When the user is in edit mode, my web part zone still says "Add a Web Part". I want to disable that as I have already added the webpart for them. Is there a way to hide that text?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a .css file included in your page layout.

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceholderID="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">
   <link id="cssLink" href="<% $SPUrl:~SiteName/LibraryName/cssName.css%>" runat="server" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</asp:Content>
```

In the cssName.css file you can do something like this,

```
ms-WPBody, ms-wpContentDivSpace
{
    font-family : Arial;
    font-size : 12px;
}
```

"Add a Web Part" links comes by default with every web-part zone. I don't think it's possible to remove this by some direct property. I am not sure about some javascript\jquery tweak. Rather, you can add the CWEP directly to the page, outside the web-part zone.